# Find a specific element in an array of Booleans while using the least amount of resources C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search

I have a hypothetical array of Booleans that contains 50 elements. The values of these booleans are unknown to me and the only way to find out the value of a specific element is to call a method and supply the element's index to it. This method is costly in terms of CPU cycles and what I am trying to do is write a code that uses the least amount of calls to this method to determine the value of a specific element.

If there is an element with a false value in this array, then all the elements before it must also be false. If there is an element with a true value in this array, then all the elements after it must also be true.

To give an example of such arrays:

```
[false, false, false, true, true, true, true]
[false, false, false, false]
[true, true]
```

The element I am looking for is, as you have guessed, the one where the changing from false to true happens, if any.

Obviously the first thing I thought of was slightly modified binary search that looks like this:

```
int FindFirstTrue(HypotheticalBool[] arr)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = arr.Length - 1;
    int mid;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        if (checkArr(arr, mid))
        {
            if (!checkArr(arr, mid-1))
            {
                return mid;
            }
            else
            {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

The `checkArr(HypotheticalBool[] arr, int elementIndex)` is the CPU hungry method I mentioned above.
In the worst case, it takes this code 11 calls to `checkArr()` to find the correct element.

What I am trying to do is bring that number down. Is there a more efficient implementation of binary search to achieve this goal?

Comment: I do not understand why you have to call `checkArr`. Why not simply `if(arr[mid])`?

Comment: Because it is not a bool[] array. It is a hypothetical boolean array. The actual values come from complex calculations. I just know that there are 50 elements in this array. And the only way to access the values is through the `checkArr`.

Comment: I suppose a more clear way to describe my problem would be: I have indices of those fifty elements but not the actual array. And to find the value of the specific index, you call the `checkArr`.

Comment: You could cache any values already computed. Also, I would remove the extra check for mid-1 and let the binary search continue until it nails down the transition point.

Comment: @Fildor The array is there whether it is an efficient way to store these values or not. I did not create the array, I just check the values.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thank you for the reply, actually I do cache the values, the code I provided is more of a pseudo code.  Will  look at the extra mid-1 check.

Comment: Questions of efficiency and performance are useless against a "hypothetical" scenario. Exactly what kind of data structure are you dealing with here?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield There is a method `checkArr` that will output a value if you supply an index of the element you want the value for. You know that there are only 50 elements and you have the indices of all 50. How the method calculates the value is a black box for the purposes of this example. It just is a CPU expensive procedure and cannot be changed. I am looking for the most efficient way to "get to the index I am looking for", rather how I can modify the logic of how the `checkArr` does what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While trying to run your algorithm I got an IndexOutOfRangeException. I had to change the second if-statement to `if (mid < 1 || !CheckArr(arr, mid - 1))`.

To simplify things I worked with a real Boolean array and added a counter to the array checking method. Then I repeated the search by filling the array with 0 up to 50 `false` values and the rest with `true` values. The mean number of counts for your `FindFirstTrue` method was **7.68** with counts in the range of 2 .. 11 (inclusive).

This can be improved, as you are calling `checkArr` twice. This is my implementation:

```cs
static int FindFirstTrue(bool[] arr)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = arr.Length - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    bool lastCheck = false;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        lastCheck = CheckArr(arr, mid);
        if (lastCheck) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    if (!lastCheck) {
        mid++;
    }
    return low < arr.Length ? mid : -1;
}
```

The mean number of counts is **5.86** with counts in the range of 5 .. 6 (inclusive). This is 23.7% less.

The theoretical number of counts for a binary search is  log<sub>2</sub>(50) ≈ 5.64. So, 5.86 is pretty close to the optimum.

But depending on the nature of your real array, this could be improved. E.g., if you have a range of numbers who approximate a known function then the problem could be transformed into root search problem. There are better algorithms for this kind of problem than binary search. See also [Root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now that I think about it, I did overcomplicate my version of the code.